# How to get json variables?

Tags: json, wordpress

I need to grab json variables from the  url [a link](http://boppanahospitals.com/js/68)!

I want to use this data into my wordpress website using  www.wordpress.org/plugins/json-data-shortcode

i want to add 2nd "Link" attribute and How to access any attribute in that json file,I am confused because there are lot of "Link" and other attributes repeating more than once

I am new to JSON ,

Please help anyone

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can because the json object from your link contains a colon `ns3:Files`.
But if the plugin supports it you can do:

```
[json src="http://boppanahospitals.com/js/68"]
The link is: {ns3:Files.File[1].Link}
[/json]
```